# Introduction title & headers

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, chapters

There are several problems which I am dealing with.

Basically, I want to eliminate "Chapter 1" from the title of my introduction. 
In order to do that, I used

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Introduction}}
```

The problem with this approach is that it does not change the headers, which remain the ones of the previous section ("Contents").

It should be noted that I have changed both the title and the headers format.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vspace*{-10ex}\Large}
{\thispagestyle{empty}\titleline[l]{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\vspace{6pt}\titlerule[.8pt]}    {\dimexpr-\baselineskip+6pt\relax}
{\LARGE\bfseries\filleft}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage\null\newpage
\tableofcontents


\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Introduction}}

\end{document}
```

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Furthermore, is it possible to restore the classic title format only for the introduction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use package `unnumeredtotoc` as seen in the [LaTeX wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Section_numbering).

`\addchap{Introduction}`  takes care of the toc entry and the corresponding header.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vspace*{-10ex}\Large}
{\thispagestyle{empty}\titleline[l]{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\vspace{6pt}\titlerule[.8pt]}    {\dimexpr-\baselineskip+6pt\relax}
{\LARGE\bfseries\filleft}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{unnumberedtotoc}% <--------------
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\addchap{Introduction}% <--------------
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the package unnumberedtotoc does not exist.

Comment: @Marco Yes, it does. There is a link to a github repo linked on the wikibook page.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/

Comment: The link can also be found in the answer to the same question linked above.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. But how can I put the title on the left?

Comment: @Marco What do you mean?

Comment: I redefined the format of the title and thus the title is displayed on the right (__________XXXX) and not on the left (XXXX_______).

Comment: Well then, simply don't do that redefinition and remove the `\fillleft`.

Comment: Yes. But the problem is that I want to do that redefinition (only) for chapters who have "chapter x" at the beginning. Is possible to do that?

Comment: @marco i would suggest to ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Change the value of `secnumdepth` locally, you won't even have to use `\addcontentsline`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vspace*{-10ex}\Large}
{\thispagestyle{empty}\titleline[l]{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\vspace{6pt}\titlerule[.8pt]} {\dimexpr-\baselineskip+6pt\relax}
{\LARGE\bfseries\filleft}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
%\maketitle
%\cleardoublepage\null\newpage
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\chapter{Introduction}    
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}    \chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]
*Added:* To have the unnumbered chapters titles flush left, add this code to your preamble:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]
{\vspace*{-10ex}\LARGE\bfseries\filright}
{} {0pt}
{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard. Do you know how to put the title on the left? 

The problem is that I have to do the same for the Conclusion. Is it possible with your suggestion?

Comment: @Marco: Do you mean the title itself (not the title in the header)? With the chapter title on the right for numbered chapters?

Comment: Yes. The title itself. I want to title format that I have redefined for numbered chapters. And the classic title format for the Introduction, the Conclusion and the Bibliography.

Comment: Do you have other unnumbered chapters?

Comment: Yes. Conclusion and Bibliography.

Comment: And table of contents. Please see my addendum.